# Scan temporal data and add a line when a date is missing

Tags: shell, unix, file-io

I am analysing big time series data files (hourly data), and have to compare them between each other on UNIX. This would be easy if the same line in each file had the same date and hour. However, some data are missing in some files, which makes that the lines from the different files do not match temporally. What I would therefore like to do is to scan the dates in my data file and add a line when an hour is missing. The example below will help understand:

This is the raw file:

```
5/3/03,11:00 AM,2.62,,30.11
5/3/03,12:00 PM,2.63,,31.92
5/3/03,1:00 PM,2.6,,37.09
5/3/03,3:00 PM,2.54,,36.46
```

See that there is a data missing the 5/3/03 at 2PM. What I therefore would like to do is add a line with the date only, in order to obtain that:

```
5/3/03,11:00 AM,2.62,,30.11
5/3/03,12:00 PM,2.63,,31.92
5/3/03,1:00 PM,2.6,,37.09
5/3/03,2:00 PM,,,
5/3/03,3:00 PM,2.54,,36.46
```

I am new in Unix and just don't see the way to do it. If you could light me it would be of great help!

Thank you in advance,
Alice

Comment: What programming languages do you know? Something like Perl would be very helpful for this.

Comment: Isn't this question more suitable on http://unix.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Which UNIX are you using?

Comment: I am working on a Mac OSX 10.8.2. Unfortunately I don't know Perl and hardly know about Unix. I am in a stage where I can understand the codes but still too fresh to be able to write it on my own.

Comment: Can't you get the data in a civilized format with at least the 24 hour clock used for the times?  Is the data a decade old?  Is the date 2003-05-03, or something else (and if so, what)?  Is there anything to stop there being two or three consecutive missing values?  What about whole days?

Answer (score 1):

Given a date, you can get the next expected date like this:

```
cdate=$(echo "5/3/03,11:00 AM,2.62,,30.11" | cut -d, -f1,2)  # from file
ndate=$(date +"%m/%d/%y,%I:%M %p" -d "${cdate/,/ } +1 hours")
```

So, after you read a line, if previous `ndate` is not equal to `cdate`, write out `ndate` in a loop. When they match, write out the line.

A Bash script using GNU date:

```
#!/bin/bash

ndate=""
while read line; do
    cdate=$(echo $line | cut -d, -f1,2)  # from file
    #echo $cdate $ndate
    if [[ "$ndate" == "" || "$ndate" == "$cdate" ]]; then
        echo $line
    else
        while [[ $ndate != $cdate ]]; do
            echo "$ndate,,,"
            ndate=$(date +"%-m/%-d/%y,%-I:%M %p" -d "${ndate/,/ } +1 hours")
        done
        echo $line
    fi
    ndate=$(date +"%-m/%-d/%y,%-I:%M %p" -d "${cdate/,/ } +1 hours")
done < input
```

Comment: Thank you Perreal. I got the idea but I am still too new to deal with the loop and everything. Would you implement that in a awk command? I am sorry to ask you such basic questions, but I have been struggling with those data for such a long time...

Comment: @Alice, added a script

Comment: Ok, as it is not working directly I will spend some more time to get into it later in the weekend. I will let you know. Thank you very much for your help, I cross my fingers for it to work!